# How can I continue handling a request in Express.js if there is no Image detected by Multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, multer

In my Express app which uses Multer, I want to receive form data which may or may not contain a file and then process it. This form data contains other data like, f.e., a name which I want to add to the database **whether there is an image attached or not**.

app.js (Node / Express / Multer)

```
app.post
(
    '/create_item', 
    multer({dest : 'temp/'}).single('image'), 
    function(req, res, next)
    {
        // I want to do stuff here with the req.body, 
        // even if there wasn't a file attached for Multer to process.
        // As of now, it just shuts down the request when there is no file.

        // When there is an image attached there is no problem.
    }
)
```

So, Multer doesn't seem to allow continuing the request if there isn't a file attached. Is there a way to continue doing stuff on the server even if there is no image attached for Multer to do something with?

I have done a lot of research and thinking to find a solution, but sadly could not find one. If you can help me out, that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you just need to update your version of multer. I ran your code on my computer and it worked. Alternatively, use my answer below.

Comment: You were probably right in this comment, though my version works fine. I discovered this only happens when I send a request from a specific page (client-side). It are probably "just" some messy vars in the page of that javascript interfering with the form data: server-side/Multer is fine. Thank you, I taught maybe it wasn't possible with Multer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit ugly of a work-around, but try this. Create our own middleware that detects whether a file is being passed through or not. If a file is coming through, use mutter, otherwise, bypass it.

```
app.post
(
    '/create_item', 
    function(req, res, next) {
        req.rawBody.indexOf('filename=') === -1 ? next() : multer({dest : 'temp/'}).single('image')(req, res, next);
    }, 
    function(req, res, next)
    {
        // I want to do stuff here with the req.body, 
        // even if there wasn't a file attached for Multer to process.
        // As of now, it just shuts down the request when there is no file.

        // When there is an image attached there is no problem.
    }
)
```